# .htaccess redirect only last portion

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've moved a WordPress website from an old version to a new version. Blog URLs are broken now. How to create a redirect that will take only the last portion of the url and append it to the domain. Here is an example:

http://www.dummydomain/3454/uncategorized/post-name-here ==>  http://www.dummydomain/post-name-here

the 3454 and the uncategorized  are different between posts so I can't hardcode that.

I searched allot but couldn't find anything related to this. Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (?:^|/)([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that did not work. It really did nothing.

Comment: Make sure this is first rule after `RewriteEngine On` and you enter URL as `http://www.dummydomain/3454/uncategorized/post-name-here` in browser.